# Angular routes does not render child components from parent

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I have an issue with routing in angular. I have a parent which is the shell component and it is loaded from app component. The Shell has the left menu and the dynamic content section on the right side. Once i click on a link in left menu, i need to render the list of of reports as tabs and each report is a child component.

Now, when i try to click on a report , the URL matches with the paths provided in reports.component.ts but it does not render the child component.

I am not sure if I am doing it the correct way.
Could anyone please advice me ?

> **app.routing.module.ts**
>
> ```
> {
>     path: 'app',
>     children: [
>       { path: 'parent/:param', loadChildren: () => import('./report-list.module').then(m => m.ReportListModule) },
>     ]
> }
> ```
>
> **app.component.html**

```
<shell></shell> <!-- Renders shell.component.html -->
```

> **shell.component.html**

```
<reports></reports>   <!-- Renders reports.component.html -->
<othermodules></othermodules>
```

> **reports.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

> **reports.component.ts**

```
 this.router.navigate(['/app/parent/report1'], { queryParams:    params}); 
 this.router.navigate(['/app/parent/report2'], {    queryParams:    params});  
 this.router.navigate(['/app/parent/report3'],    {    queryParams:    params});       
 this.router.navigate(['/app/parent/report4'], {    queryParams:          params});
```

> **report-list.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [   
{ path: 'app/parent/report1', component: Report1Component },   
{ path: 'app/parent/report2', component: Report2Component },
{ path: 'app/parent/report3', component: Report3Component },
{ path: 'app/parent/report4', component: Report4Component } ];

@NgModule({   declarations: [],   imports: [
    Report1Module,
     Report2Module,
     Report3Module,
    Report4Module,
     RouterModule.forChild(routes)   ] })
```

Comment: Your app/shell component does not have a router outlet ?

Comment: No, They dont have. If i try to add , the component loads two times and i will see two left menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue with the below changes.

```
this.router.navigate(['/app/parent/reports/report1'], { queryParams:    params}); 

const routes: Routes = [   
{ path: 'app/parent/reports/report1', component: Report1Component },
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you dont need to define child route with full path.

report-list.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [   
{ path: 'report1', component: Report1Component },   
{ path: 'report2', component: Report2Component },
{ path: 'report3', component: Report3Component },
{ path: 'report4', component: Report4Component } ];
```

// Code for routing link

```
 this.router.navigate(['app/parent/report1'], { queryParams:    params}); 
 this.router.navigate(['app/parent/report2'], {    queryParams:    params});  
 this.router.navigate(['app/parent/report3'],    {    queryParams:    params});       
 this.router.navigate(['app/parent/report4'], {    queryParams:          params});
```

Comment: Unfortunately no